How do I prevent my Control from auto-scaling when receiving the WM_DPICHANGED_BEFOREPARENT and WM_DPICHANGED_AFTERPARENT messages?
I added a manifest like this.
<asmv3:application>
    <asmv3:windowsSettings>
      <dpiAware 
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
          true/PM
      </dpiAware>
      <dpiAwareness 
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">
          PerMonitorV2, PerMonitor
      </dpiAwareness>
    </asmv3:windowsSettings>
 </asmv3:application>

And I can receive WM_DPICHANGED_BEFOREPARENT and WM_DPICHANGED_AFTERPARENT message.
In the current situation, when I move the window screen from 100% scale to 200% scale monitor, Control & bitmap are auto scaled.
But I want it to stay 100% -> 100% because I want to Customize the Control & bitmap & Font size, position. (OnDPIChanged_BEFOREPARENT()...)
Is there a way?
I tried changing the file properties:

I changed it, but "WM_DPIChangedBefore,After" does not occur.

You should [edit] and post some relevant code, (at least OnDPIChanged_BEFOREPARENT(), but possibly more) and you should also add pictures of what you expect and what you actually get.
